# Native Base picker: how to add margin/padding to top?

Tags: react-native, native-base, react-native-picker-select, react-native-picker

In my React Native app I'm using the Native Base picker. On the iPhone 12 emulator, when the list to select from pops up it's pushed far to the top of the screen, and I have to tap just below the `Back` button for it to work. How can I put padding/margin above this screen?

[image]

Comment: SOLVED: Use the `headerStyle` prop.

Comment: you can wrap your picker under the view Tags. And you can style your view.

Answer (score 0):

Wrap your Views with Safeareaview from react native components
https://reactnative.dev/docs/safeareaview
Read more about the component here

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).